# Scrappy' method re() doesn't work with Unicode strings

Tags: unicode, scrapy

I'm working in Windows 7 and scrappy interactive console (based on IPython).

I'm doing step [Trying Selectors in the Shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#trying-selectors-in-the-shell) in the tutorial

If i grab some site with english letters title, all is okay, like in the tutorial:

```
In [5]: hxs.select('//title/text()').re('(\w+):')`
Out[5]: [u'Computers', u'Programming', u'Languages', u'Python']`
```

But if i grab site with non-english letters (russian, Unicode), re() method does not return anything:

```
In [25]: hxs.select('//title/text()').re('(\w+)')
Out[25]: []
```

There is some text in Title, it is not empty:

```
In [24]: hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()
Out[24]: [u'\u041b\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0446\u0438\u043e\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a \u0430\u0431\u043e\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432']
```

Help me, can i use scrapy' re() with unicode symbols?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Scrapy isn't using the `re.UNICODE` flag for its regexes, so `\w` isn't including all the Unicode-defined "word" characters.

The docs seem to indicate that Scrapy's `.re` can take an already-compiled regex, so you could try compiling your regex yourself with the `UNICODE` flag:

```
import re
hxs.select('//title/text()').re(re.compile('(\w+)', re.UNICODE))
```

Comment: But do you have any ideas why re.UNICODE flag doenst apply to regex by default?

Comment: I would've expected Scrapy to set that flag internally, but a peek at the source code [indicates otherwise](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/0.15.1/scrapy/utils/misc.py#L69).

Comment: Fixed [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/e9184def35734031eed8d48b2fae952c36ba8be1)